# Problems with plugin Codesnippet ckeditor Textarea

Tags: ckeditor, code-snippets

I'm using Ckeditor version 4.5
I want to use pulgin Codesnippet with Textarea. But it does not show well.
I used to tag Div, everything is normal:

Please help me use textarea

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the official demo http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/codesnippet.html. There is also a sample code at the bottom page, you can try to use it. You may also look into the dev console for any errors.

Comment: Hi,This is my Code when load form:

Comment: @Thanhansoft, I think your code got accidentally deleted. You could add it in your initial post or attach a link to e.g. jsfiddle or codepen snippet.